# How to use AND in two string methods

Tags: java, string, compare

Here when I try to execute the program it works only with @ but it doesn't check for .com or .ca. How should I fix this?

```
System. out.println("Enter your email:");
email = input.next();
while (!email.contains("@") && !email.endsWith(".com") || !email.contains("@") && !email.endsWith(".ca"))
{
    System. out.println("Your email is not valid");
    return;
}
```

Basically my email should contain both @ and `.com` or @ and `.ca`, Otherwise email is invalid will be shown.

Comment: `valid = email.contains("@") && (email.ends(".com") || email.ends(".ca")); if (!valid)...`

Comment: is valid going to be a boolean type?

Comment: yes, result of condition is boolean

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a logic operation. || instead &&.

```
  while (!email.contains("@") || !email.endsWith(".com") || !email.endsWith(".ca"))
{
   System. out.println("Your email is not valid");
  return;
}
```

in your case, if you have @ but haven't .com (for example) then you'll get false in result (because of &&) and your cycle will finish.